# Soap web service and iOS client, always have error HTTP 200?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services, soap

I'm making a connection between soap web service and iOS app and connecting is done, but I get an error HTTP 200.

How I can solve this error?

---

**Code**

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
{
    dig = @"م ط ر" ;
    cha =@"0158";

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<s:Body>"
                             "<GetCarDataByPlate xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                             "<params>"
                             "<PlateDigits>%@</PlateDigits>"
                             "<PlateStr>%@</PlateStr>"
                             "<Pass>Mob.2013</Pass>"
                             "</params>"
                             "</GetCarDataByPlate>"
                             "</s:Body>"
                             "</s:Envelope>",dig,cha];

    NSLog(@"%@", soapMessage);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.uis.com.sa/Wcf_MobileS/MobileService.svc?wsdl"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/IMobileService/GetCarDataByPlate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];





    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"theConnection = %@",theConnection);


    if(theConnection)
    {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"WebData = %@",webData);

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is null");
    }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
{
    [webData setLength:0];
    NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse;

    httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

    NSLog(@"HTTP error %zd", (ssize_t) httpResponse.statusCode);

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
  //  NSLog(@"webdata: %@", data);

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"error with the connection");
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received bytes %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"xml %@",theXML);
}
```

Comment: what u get in your Log because 200 is code for OK not for error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the HTTP status-code (not error-code!) within `didReceiveResponse` which obviously is a good sign. HTTP status-code 200 means **OK**.

---

> 200 OK
>
> The request has succeeded. The information returned with the response
>   is dependent on the method used in the request, for example:
>
> GET an entity corresponding to the requested resource is sent in the
>   response;
>
> HEAD the entity-header fields corresponding to the requested resource
>   are sent in the response without any message-body;
>
> POST an entity describing or containing the result of the action;
>
> TRACE an entity containing the request message as received by the end
>   server.

Taken from the [W3 Status Code Definitions - rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

---

Go ahead and print that `httpResponse` into the console from within that very same method.

Comment: thank you for quick Ansar 
'CarEnquire[1060:c07] theConnection = <NSURLConnection: 0x825e750>
CarEnquire[1060:c07] WebData = <>
CarEnquire[1060:c07] HTTP error 200
CarEnquire[1060:c07] DONE. Received bytes 356'